# Combinational Circuit: How can 2.5 and 3.5 be represented in a 3-bit truth table?

Tags: binary, truth-table, decimal, combinatorial-logic

Design of a combinational circuit with 3 inputs, x, y, z, and 3 outputs, A, B, C. When binary input is 0, 1, 2, or 3, the binary output is twice the input. When binary input is 4, 5, 6, or 7, binary output is half the input. How can 5 and 7, the outputs of which are 2.5 and 3.5, respectively, be represented in the truth table? Here is the truth table that I have filled out as much as possible.

[image]

Comment: I don't think there's a bright-line answer -- or an objective reality -- that could tell you how to handle it. Either you are supposed to truncate, or round according to some rules. And if you round, by which of several possible rules? So you will have to decide the matter, I think. For us, it would only be an array of differing "opinions." You are in a better place to decide this.

Comment: As given, this homework cannot be done. There is such a thing like a fixed-point binary, but it needs 4 bits, as the largest value is 6 and the resolution is 0.5. 3 bits will be left to the point and 1 right to it. If you are supposed to round, you cannot differentiate between results. Please get back to your teacher and ask for clarification.

Comment: I'd guess your instructor is getting you to realize the limitations of binary math.  I'd go with 2 and 3.